# Combing Actual and Budget Data based on date cutoff Power BI Dax

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a forecast that is dynamic, meaning if I select a date range, it should calculate the actuals up to the max selected date, and then add budget values for the remaining fiscal periods.

I am working with a fiscal year that goes from August to July. I have data for August 2022 to July 2023. I have a date table, but I can't figure out how to have the DAX know when to start and when to end.

For example, if I have the date filter on for 08/01/2022 - 04/30/23, then the DAX should calculate the forecast by combining actuals from 08/01/2022 - 04/30/2023 with budget data for 05/01/23 - 07/31/2023.

I tried using the following formula, but it only works when my fiscal period is calendar year-based, i.e., January to December. I have a measure that sums all budget data [TotalBudIncome] and another measure that sums all actual income data [TotalActIncome].

To clarify, the following formula was using a parameter value that can only go from 1 - 12 as I could only generate a series from 1 to 12. Also, the data I have ranges from Feb 2021 to Dec 2023:

```
ResiIncomeRFX =
IF(
    MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Date])) <= Parameter[Parameter Value],
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            'Date',
            MONTH('Date'[Date]) <= Parameter[Parameter Value]
        ),
        [TotalActIncome]
    ),
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            'Date',
            MONTH('Date'[Date]) > Parameter[Parameter Value]
        ),
        [TotalBudIncome]
    )
)
+
IF(
    MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Date])) <= Parameter[Parameter Value],
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            'Date',
            MONTH('Date'[Date]) > Parameter[Parameter Value]
        ),
        [TotalBudIncome]
    ),
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            'Date',
            MONTH('Date'[Date]) <= Parameter[Parameter Value]
        ),
        [TotalActIncome]
    )
)
```

Expected Results:

[image: Expected Results]

Data Sample:

[image: Data Sample]